# If a game object is a child to a parent object, would children of the child count as children to the primary parent object?

Tags: unity

In my game, I have an Empty Object called Cars that acts as the overall parent object to the vehicles being added. However, the cars being added have children attached to them. I am trying to add a script that differentiates between the cars within the Cars object to decide which one the player will control based on where the player controller is interacting (each car has a trigger around it that, if the player presses "1" next to it will change to the car controller).

I am trying to figure out a for loop to go through each child of Cars and comparing it to the trigger the player is interacting with. Would the children of each vehicle count towards the overall childCount of the Cars object?

For Reference

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnterCar : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Cars;
    public GameObject car;
    public GameObject carCamera;
    public GameObject playerCamera;
    public GameObject player;

    private void Start()
    {
        Cursor.visible = false;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        string targetCar = other.gameObject.name;
        //For Loop to decide which car to control here
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Alpha1))
        {
            car.GetComponent<CarController>().enabled = true;
            carCamera.SetActive(true);
            playerCamera.SetActive(false);
            player.SetActive(false);
            player.GetComponent<EnterCar>().enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Transform.childCount](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-childCount.html) only counts direct children of a game object , children of children are ignored.

Comment: Why "search" for the right car? Can't you use "other" Collider to directly get the target car?